# How to put Hex values in byte array

Tags: java, arrays, hex, byte, apache-commons

The buffer is a byte array containing 7 bytes

```
The number is 1234567
The hex value is 0x12d687
```

The goal is to put the last 4 digits of the hex value to the first 2 bytes and last 2 bytes of the buffer

```
   expected output of the 7 bytes buffer = D6 87 00 00 00 D6 87
```

For the first conversion, I used

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Test;

    @Test
    public void test(){
   
    
        String number = "1234567";
        String hexString = Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(number));       
        System.out.println(hexString);
    
        byte[] decodeHex = Hex.decodeHex(hexString);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(decodeHex));
    }
```

For the next part, I'm struggling to put it to the byte array as it auto converts it.

I used Apache commons in the conversion above and got the following results (which is not what I wanted)

```
12d687
[18, -42, -121]
```

Comment: Numbers are numbers, not decimal, hexadecimal or binary. It's how you represent them when printing that changes how they appear.

Comment: As @FedericoklezCulloca says, numbers are just numbers. The bytes in your array are correct.